# Serialization/mapping issue Dropwizard/Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, jersey-client, dropwizard

I am trying to map a REST-call with my POJO. The POJO looks like this:

```
public class ResultWrapper implements Serializable{

  private int total;
  private List<Movies> movies; ... getters and setters
```

In the call I use:

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(RequestURI + URLEncoder.encode(movie, "UTF-8"));

ResultWrapper result = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ResultWrapper.class);
```

The error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class models.ResultWrapper, and Java type class models.ResultWrapper, and MIME media type text/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1 was not found
```

Client is a Jersey client. I have tried making the call from Chrome (Postman) and it sais that the application type returned is "text/javascript", not "application/json" as one would expect? I think that would be my problem.

Is there any way I can get the ObjectMapper to resolve that it is actually "application/json" and not "text/javascript". I have tried using String.class and then I get the Json object just fine.

My purpose is to use automatic mapping from Jersey Client.

Thanks for any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2):

try adding annotation `@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Provider
@Produces(application/json)
public class YourTestBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<ResultWrapper> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourTestBodyWriter.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return ResultWrapper.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(
        ResultWrapper t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(
        ResultWrapper t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        String message = t.someMethod()
        entityStream.write(message.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        LOG.info(message);
    }

}
```

Add in your app run():

```
// Serializer
environment.jersey().register(new YourTestBodyWriter ());
```

Thats the normal way in your application.